# SharePoint 2010 - Count number of people in a people picker field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

As the title suggests, I need to get the number of people from a SharePoint 2010 people picker field.

I'm creating a training booking system and need to set a limit on the number of people that can attend an appointment in a SharePoint calendar.

At the moment I've got a workflow adding a 1 to a counter every time a user is added. But I'd prefer it through a workflow counting the users or a calculated column.

Any suggestions?